# backup full sms/mms contents via adb

Tags: android

I've been attempting to use adb to pull the sms/mms inbox in its entirety from the device but am having some trouble. The phone is rooted and I've tried the following commands:

Input

```
./adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db
```

output

```
Permission denied
```

Input

```
./adb pull su /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db
```

Output

```
The help menu
```

Am I flawed in my thinking that I can pull the sms inbox via commands similar to the ones I've tried? If it can be done what is wrong with my command?

Thanks

Comment: What also works fine for me is using [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) on my rooted phone

Comment: On my device, it's placed under `/data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

One way to fetch contents of the /data directory is to first copy the sqlite db to somewhere that is accessible, and then using adb pull to copy from there to the host.

For example, the following commands use the android bridge to grab the sms data (assuming it is contained in /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db):

```
adb shell
$ mkdir /mnt/sdcard/tmp
# su
# cat /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db > /mnt/sdcard/tmp/mmssms.db
# exit
$ exit
adb pull /mnt/sdcard/tmp/mmssms.db .
```

Now you have the mms/sms database on your host machine, probe to find most popular recipient, for example:

```
sqlite3 -header mmssms.db 'select address from sms' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Finally, tidy up the temp area:

```
adb shell
$ rm /mnt/sdcard/tmp/mmssms.db
$ rmdir /mnt/sdcard/tmp
$ exit
```

Comment: Could you please explain the commented lines `# ...` after `adb shell` ? When should we execute them?

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong they aren't comments, they are a change in the shell prompt due to switching to `su` ("super user") mode.  I don't have a device I can test this with right now, and it might have changed in the last 7 years, but I think I put the first `#` one step too early.  In any case, you run them sequentially. The `# exit` leaves the su mode, while the `$ exit` leaves adb shell.

Comment: Currently if you try `su` in adb shell (at least on my Android 10 production device), it gives an error, "/system/bin/sh: su: inaccessible or not found"

Answer (score 8):

You have to give ADB root privalages before you pull that database

```
adb root

adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db ./
```

Comment: Nowadays (Android 10 at least) if you try `adb root`, it says "adbd cannot run as root in production builds".

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Bonlenfum's answer I was able to come up with a reusable script for copying any file/directory on a rooted device to a Windows path (local or UNC).

---

**Edit**: Fixed bug with paths containing spaces.

---

Save the following as: **adbSuPull.bat**

```
@echo off

SetLocal
set RemotePath=%~1
set LocalPath=%~f2

if [%1] == [] goto Usage
if "%~1" == "/?" goto Usage
if not [%3] == [] goto Usage

:: Replace " " with "\ " (escape spaces)
set RemotePath=%RemotePath: =\ %

set TimeStamp=%date:~-4,4%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%_%time:~-11,2%-%time:~-8,2%-%time:~-5,2%

:: Replace spaces with zeros
set TimeStamp=%TimeStamp: =0%

if "%LocalPath%" == "" set LocalPath=adbSuPull_%UserName%_%TimeStamp%
set SdCardPath=/mnt/sdcard
set TempPath=%SdCardPath%/adbSuPull_temp_%TimeStamp%/

echo.
echo Copying to temp location "%TempPath%"
echo.
adb shell "su -c 'mkdir -p %TempPath%; cp -RLv %RemotePath% %TempPath%'"

echo.
echo Copying to destination "%LocalPath%"
echo.
adb pull "%TempPath%" "%LocalPath%"
if ErrorLevel 0 goto Cleanup

:Error
echo.
echo Operation failed. Is USB Storage in use?
echo.
pause
call Cleanup
exit /b 1

:Cleanup
echo.
echo Removing temp location "%TempPath%"
echo.
adb shell "rm -Rf '%TempPath%'"
exit /b ErrorLevel

:Usage
echo.
echo.adbSuPull ^<RemotePath^> [^<LocalPath^>]
echo.
echo Copies files/directories from a rooted Android device to a Windows path.
echo Author: Ben Lemmond benlemmond@codeglue.org
echo.
echo.  RemotePath (required)  Specifies the path to the file or directory on
echo.                         the rooted Android device.
echo.
echo.  LocalPath (optional)   Specifies the destination path. This can be a
echo.                         Windows local path (C:\folder) or a UNC path
echo.                         (\\server\share).
echo.                         Defaults to adbSuPull_%%UserName%%_%%TimeStamp%%
echo.                         in the current working directory.
exit /b 1
```

---

Usage:

```
adbSuPull <RemotePath> [<LocalPath>]

Copies files/directories from a rooted Android device to a Windows path.
Author: Ben Lemmond benlemmond@codeglue.org

  RemotePath (required)  Specifies the path to the file or directory on
                         the rooted Android device.

  LocalPath (optional)   Specifies the destination path. This can be a
                         Windows local path (C:\folder) or a UNC path
                         (\\server\share).
                         Defaults to adbSuPull_%UserName%_%TimeStamp%
                         in the current working directory.
```