# Extracting SMS (touchscreen broken, device not rooted, HTC Wildfire)

Tags: android, sms

I have an HTC Wildfire S A510e (Android 2.3.5, not rooted). I want to extract my SMS messages and import them into another device.

Problems:

- There is no free space on the internal memory left. No apps such as SMS backup can be installed.
- The touchscreen is broken, I cannot unlock the display or use any buttons (e.g. home, back, search).
- Device is not rooted. I cannot view the contents of /data/ or erase anything inside it using `adb shell`.

In which directory are SMS messages stored on HTC devices? I could then perhaps use the following command to obtain a backup, as it works without root permissions:

```
adb pull <backupfile>
```

What format does the SMS database have? Perhaps I can search the filesystem for that file-extension?

Is it possible to root a phone if there is no internal memory left?

Comment: With adb access, you can at least deinstall some apps to get free internal space.

Answer (score 1):

SMS messages are stored in a SQLite database within the data folder of the messaging app. The extension of the database should be `.db`.

Although I'm unfamiliar with HTC devices, it should be located here:

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db
```

Perhaps you can try pulling that file via `adb`?

Comment: I doubt that he can access `/data` without root...

Comment: Yes, root is needed to read anything under `/data`. With root, [this answer should suffice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13904529/154306), but if rooting is really not an option, it *is* possible to read the database out programmatically (i.e. install an app).

Comment: So the best way would be: Create an app that exports the sms database to the sdcard and register a broadcast receiver to `BOOT_COMPLETED` and restart your phone, than you should be able to pull the export file from the sdcard...

Comment: Just tested: the broadcast receiver is not necessary. If you run your app from eclipse, the onCreate() of the activity is executed even with turned off screen.

Comment: "/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db" is the right file on HTC Wildfire.
However, I can't copy or even display it with cat-command.
It says "Permission denied".

Comment: @WarrenFaith Correct. Also you can open apps using the ActivityManager ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5494891/154306)).

Comment: @Hello_World Either you'll need to root, or make some space to install an app that backs up the database without any user interaction.

Comment: This question is off-topic here, and about to be deleted, but it looks like your answer contains some useful information that I would hate to be lost forever. Perhaps you could consider posting it over on the Android Q&A site, like in response to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/htc-desire-crashed-deleted-all-sms-mms-can-i-recover)?