# manually backup sms/mms database on kitkat

Tags: android, sms, adb

i've seen this post
[backup full sms/mms contents via adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266374/backup-full-sms-mms-contents-via-adb)

but i know that kitkat changed some stuff to do with sms so i don't know if this is still correct.

Can someone more knowledgable than i please confirm?

(the reason i want to do a manual backup of sms/mms database is summarized here
http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/disable-touchscreen-z2-t3080520)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got impatient and tested this out myself.
This still works for kitkat.

copied both

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db
/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db-journal
```

using the method outlined in the other SO question.

Comment: device/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db